# How to Adjust Picture Size

Tags: html

I am excited to complete this project, i'm getting close but need help.
I want the width on the download now button equal the width of the book? 
http://www.orcaaccounting.com/freeStuff.html | 
Then make the image size be mobile friendly.  Right now the page isn't mobile friendly.
Any other pointers are greatly appreciated.

Here is a url to my source code.

I couldn't figure out how to insert the code here.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Instead of posting your code as URL, please show us your code as text.

Comment: I thought it was messy so I didnt post it.  Here it is, oh now the code is too long:

Comment: Just post important pieces of code

Comment: <div style="display:flex;justify-content:space-around;margin:75px;">
<div id="healthy-eating">
<a href="/opt-inform.html">
<img src="helathyCookingMenu.png" /><br/>
<img src="downloadnowOrange.png" />
</a>
</div>
<div id="what-I-learned">
<a href="/opt-inform.html">
<img src="whatILearnedLosingAHalfMillionDollars2.png" /><br/>
<img src="downloadnowOrange.png" />

Here it is

Comment: Bad idea to style with inline style, using the HTML `style` attribute. It takes precedent over all other style besides JavaScript. Learn HTML, CSS, and JavaScript at the minimum. People often make the mistake of thinking these things are easy because the use the internet everyday. You may just want to hire someone.

Comment: agree.we are just patching this together. Im out of cash to fire a VA for this.

Comment: @JesseWilliamMacDougall Was the below answer helpful to you? If so, please select it as the "correct" answer *(by clicking the checkmark beside an answer)* to close the question, or else please provide an answer yourself and choose that as the correct answer. Otherwise, please add comments below one of the answers or edit your original question to add more detail so that additional answers can be provided. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 1):

If these are fixed images (i.e. they will not change), then all you need to do is manually set the width of the download button to be the same as the width of the book's image:

```
<img src="downloadnowOrange.png" style="width:182px">
```

Note that the above is considered bad code, but it works perfectly and since the rest of your site uses that same style, we'll leave it like that.

How did I discover the correct width for the button? If you are using Google Chrome browser, you can right-click on the book image and choose "Inspect Element". This opens Chrome's "DevTools" window and shows you the underlying HTML. If you hover over the img src, Chrome will display the image and the width/height sizes.

A few points:

You are using inline styling. This means that you have style attributes on each div/etc that style the element. For many reasons, this is not optimal. It is pretty easy to fix this. Give each DIV a unique className, and create a style tag in the document's `head` with the styles, like this:

Inline-styling (Bad):

```
<div style="width:50px;height:80px;background:red;">
   <img src="healthyCooking.png" style="border:1px solid green;"/>
</div>
```

Using a style tag:

```
<head>
   <style>
      .redDiv{width:50px;height:80px;background:red;}
      .cookImg{border:1px solid green;}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="redDiv">
      <img src="cookingBooking.png" class="cookImg" />
   </div>
```

That's what people mean by inline styling. Try not to do it. Use the 2nd method, or, better yet, use an external style sheet. To turn the style tag example into an external style sheet, you just move the lines between the `<style>` and `</style>` tags - exactly as they are into an external text file (for e.g. `mystyle.css`), then the head becomes:

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css" type="text/css" >
</head>
```

The file mystyle.css looks like this:

```
.redDiv{width:50px;height:80px;background:red;}
.cookImg{border:1px solid green;}
```

Comment: Excellent thanks for the response! The page is looking better now:
http://www.orcaaccounting.com/freeStuff.html

How do I make the space smaller between the two widgets now?

How do I make it mobile friendly?

Comment: The most important thing to do to make it mobile friendly is to change all sizing units from `px` to a variable unit like `vw` or `%` or `rem`: e.g. `font-size: 1.3vw`. See [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/). *(A viewport is a device's screen)* Really, though, you will probably want the page to dynamically reformat itself based on the screen size of the viewing device, which is what **Bootstrap** was written for. There is a [great tutorial here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_company.asp) - it will be the best 30 minutes you've ever spent.

Comment: To quickly bring the two book divs together: (1) Give the 1st and 4th (empty) divs a class: `<div class="mtdiv"></div>` and style them: `.mtdiv{width:200px;}` -- adjust the 200px as desired until the width is what you want. (Of course, you can also use inline styling on ***each*** div, like this: `style="width:200px"` )